# Flutter Firestore transaction running multiple times

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore documentation says:

> "In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire transaction again. For example, if a transaction reads documents and another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore retries the transaction. This feature ensures that the transaction runs on up-to-date and consistent data."

I am using the cloud_firestore package and I noticed that doing

```
final TransactionHandler transaction = (Transaction tx) async {
  DocumentSnapshot ds = await tx.get(userAccountsCollection.document(id));
  return ds.data;
};
return await runTransaction(transaction).then((data){
    return data;
});
```

the transaction may run multiple times but always return after the first transaction. Now in case of concurrent edits, the first transaction data may be incorrect so this is a problem for me.

How can I wait for the transaction to actually finish even if it will run multiple times and not return after the first one finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transaction code doesn't make any sense.  It's not getting the contents of any documents.  You only need to use a transaction if you intend to read, modify, and write at least one document.

The transaction function might only be run once anyway.  There is only need for it to run multiple times if the server sees that there are a lot of other transactions occurring on documents, and it's having trouble keeping up with them all.

Comment: This is my transaction I just didn't add it because I thought it is irrelevant in this case.

`
final TransactionHandler transaction = (Transaction tx) async {
DocumentSnapshot ds = await tx.get(userAccountsCollection.document(id));
      return ds.data;
    };
`

Comment: Please edit your question with all the relevant code.  Don't paste it into a comment where it's difficult to read.

Comment: My answer stands.  You're just reading a document but not writing it.  The transaction is still not necessary in this case, and the function is only going to be run once since there's no possibility for contention that requires multiple executions.

Comment: I understand. Thank you